# How to use mysql NOT IN clause if it supposed to depend on the array data

Tags: php, mysql

```
questions

 q_id|question
    1|What is the population of earth
    2|Who is tallest person in the world
    3|what makes people to cheat
```

The above table shows the questions and their ids

```
 user  
user_id|q_id
  2013 |1
  2013 |2
  1785 |3
```

This is showing (q_id)questions which the user answered.

I am struggling to retrieve the questions that the user didn't answer.
Here is my query

```
 $sql =sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user' ");
```

by looping through i get the data and assign it to the array called $questions

my goal is to get the none answered questions this is what i did

```
$query =sprintf("SELECT * FROM nyuku_questions WHERE q_id NOT IN($quesition ) order by rand() limit 1")
```

which is not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not that far from having found a solution :)

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE q_id NOT IN(SELECT q_id FROM user WHERE user_id = '". $userid ."') order by rand() LIMIT 1;
```

Of course we suppose that $userid has been checked/verified before sending it as parameters

Answer (score 2):

`left join` is a good solution for this.

```
select user.*
  from user
    left join questions
      on user.q_id = questions.q_id
  where questions.q_id is null;
```

It will match all rows in the user table to the corresponding rows in the question table. If there is no match, it will fill in `null` for all the questions values. We simply filter for that in the `where` clause.

If you want to use `not in`, it would be like this:

```
select * 
  from questions q
  where q.q_id not in (
    select q_id from user
      where user_id = "USER ID YOU ARE LOOKING FOR"
  )
```

Comment: i think i am looking for the opposite of ur answer  because this query (left join ) it is actually retrieving the data that the person has already answered and i am looking for none answered questions.I am trying to use the full outer join so far after u gave me the hint on left join but i does not work also

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed oops. i typo'd the first query (well, made a mistake if we're being honest) please try it again. i used `= null` instead of `is null` -- two completely different results